# DataReader within a DataReader

Tags: c#, datareader

I have a DataReader...I use the result of the DataReader as parameter on another DataReader that is connected to a command with a Stored Procedure type. It works fast for now but I worry about the time when my database is filled with information. How can I speed things up? Thanks

Comment: Create a test database and fill it with gigabytes of info.

Answer (score 4):

Likely, your initial query could stand to join to the results generated by the sproc.

Comment: This is the right solution.  At a minimum, you are keeping database resources open while you execute n sub-queries nested in that query.  Let the sql engine do that work for you.  That's what sql is good at - set operations.

Comment: Even without any added/tangible performance benefits, this also creates a tidier solution -- subjective, sure, but doesn't require a performance analysis to argue for -- which is why I would chose it. I'm lazy :)

Comment: shouldn't have to argue with performance analysis for poor code.  you should have to argue for a performance analysis when you are adding complexity or additional moving parts to optimize something.  as you pointed out, it's faster and tidier!  It's a pet peeve of mine when folks justify poor code under the umbrella of don't optimize what isn't a bottleneck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have 2 database round-trips instead of one. This *may* be a performance problem if you call this frequently **and** the result is small **and** you have already optimized both query and the stored procedure (so the round-trip overhead becomes significant relative to the actual useful work).

Benchmark and see if this piece of functionality is actually a bottleneck. If yes, you may try to "merge" these two operations at the SQL level, so they can be executed server-size in one go.

I'm not sure if this is related to your question, but keep in mind that (depending on your DBMS / ADO.NET provider), multiple active readers on the same connection may or may not be supported. Are you closing the first `DbDataReader` before opening the second one? If no, and you happen to switch to a different DBMS, there may be trouble. If memory serves me well, Oracle (ODP.NET) and DB2 support multiple readers, while MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL (Npgsql) don't.

Comment: Branko...You're right, I have more than one database round trips. If the first read contains let's say 5 entries, that would loop five times. While the reader reads, another reader is inside of it. I use the result of the first reader to the reader under it while it loops. Inside every read of the first reader, I open a connection, closes it and re-opens a new one when it loops back. I tried to put the connection in a pool but didn't get much of the differences. What do you think could be the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: And by the way, i have multiple instances of datareaders so that i would not worry about closing the other reader. This is because if I close the first reader and use the same variable to assign a new reader, that would dispose the reader. As a result, the reader's data will not be available when it loops back.

Comment: @Hakkai So you have "outer" reader that stays active while the "inner" reader gets re-created over and over again? My initial understanding was that there is only one "outer" and only one "inner" reader (and no loop). BTW, just assigning a variable does not dispose variable's old value. Even if everything works right now, ensure that you call `Dispose` or `Close` on old "inner" reader before creating a new one in the next iteration of the loop. I can't know for sure from the info you provided, but you may want to consider a JOIN at the database level, so there is only one reader necessary.

Comment: I am now working my way to have a single procedure on the database level. I am foreseeing a big change in performance since I will be executing a single procedure from my code and will not be needing to call other procedure as the first loops back. Thanks for the idea. I just have to change my codes now for assigning the values retrieved.

Comment: It happens that the first is the easiest way to retrieved the information I need but I can not risk the performance. Thanks.